# elisp: create dynamic menu with easy-menu and evaluate part of code during creation and not when called

Tags: elisp, dynamic-code

I'm trying to create a dynamic menu for my own compiling plugin, but I have hit a wall. This is the code that I have at the moment:

```
(defun mme-tools-create-menu ()
  (easy-menu-define mme-tools-menu erlang-mode-map "MME-Tools-Menu" 
    '("MME-Tools"
      ("Current Subsystem"
       ["Run gmake" mme-tools-build]
       ["Build beams" mme-tools-build-beam]
       ["Run Posttest" mme-tools-build-posttest]
       ["Run Move" mme-tools-build-move])
      ("Build Subsystem")))
  (dolist (path mmepaths)
    (if (string-match "code" path)
        (let* ((ss (file-name-base path))
               (uss (upcase ss)))
          (easy-menu-add-item mme-tools-menu '("Build Subsystem") 
                              [uss (mme-tools-build-path-subsystem " -j10 beam" (getenv ss))])))))
```

What I want the code to do is to make a sub-menu called "Build Subsystem" and fill it with entries. But no entries are created. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you do something like

```
(easy-menu-define mme-tools-menu erlang-mode-map "MME-Tools-Menu"
  `("MME-Tools"
    ("Current Subsystem"
     ["Run gmake" mme-tools-build]
     ["Build beams" mme-tools-build-beam]
     ["Run Posttest" mme-tools-build-posttest]
     ["Run Move" mme-tools-build-move])
    ("Build Subsystem"
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (path)
                 (when (string-match "code" path)
                   (let* ((ss (file-name-base path))
                          (uss (upcase ss)))
                     (vector uss `(mme-tools-build-path-subsystem " -j10 beam" (getenv ',ss))))))))))
```

Comment: I tried it but sadly it doesn't work, I have added mmepaths to the mapcar command so that is not the problem.

Comment: Yeah that is true, this is the error message I get from emacs: 
`File mode specification error: (error "Invalid menu item in easymenu")`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you might be looking for something like this, but it's hard to know without seeing more code.  You should be able to debug this yourself, using `macroexpand` etc. until you get a proper set of arguments to pass to `easy-menu-define`.

Wrt Stefan's code, this adds the missing `mapcar` second arg, as you mentioned, and it removes the backquote before `(mme-tools-build-path-subsystem...)` (just a guess).

```el
(easy-menu-define
    mme-tools-menu
    erlang-mode-map "MME-Tools-Menu"
    `("MME-Tools"
      ("Current Subsystem"
       ["Run gmake" mme-tools-build]
       ["Build beams" mme-tools-build-beam]
       ["Run Posttest" mme-tools-build-posttest]
       ["Run Move" mme-tools-build-move])
      ("Build Subsystem"
       ,@(mapcar (lambda (path)
                   (when (string-match "code" path)
                     (let* ((ss (file-name-base path))
                            (uss (upcase ss)))
                       (vector uss
                               (mme-tools-build-path-subsystem
                                 " -j10 beam" (getenv ',ss))))))
                 mmepaths))))
```